# The Nexus - when does its ability resolve?

Tags: smash-up

I'm confused about the base from the Science Fiction Double Feature expansion.

> The Nexus (19; 3, 3, 2): The winner replaces this base with a base of his or her choice from the base discard pile, if possible.

I'm unclear about the timing of the replacement. Does this ability resolve before or after the base scores?

If it's before, what is the point of printing victory points on the card? Its value would always be dictated by the base that replaces it.

If it's after, why isn't this ability worded similar to The Mothership and other bases in the base set, something like "After this base scores, the winner replaces this base with..."?

I play it as after, though the change in wording caused me to doubt my interpretation.

Also, what happens if there are no bases in the base discard pile, does the base get replaced from the base draw pile as usual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm unclear about the timing of the replacement. Does this ability resolve before or after the base scores?

The ability doesn't cause the base to replaced. It simply changes *how* it is replaced.

Bases are replaced at the end of the base scoring process. A base is normally discarded and replaced by one from the face-down base pile. Nexus is instead replaced by one from the discard pile if possible.

This happens after points are assigned.

> If it's after, why isn't this ability worded similar to The Mothership and other bases in the base set

Space on the card? Better wording?

> Also, what happens if there are no bases in the base discard pile, does the base get replaced from the base draw pile as usual?

Yes. If Nexus isn't capable of changing what normally happens, then it doesn't.